# Why does this SQL query not return the expected result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to run a query on my database where I retrieve all results from the Employees table if there is a matching result in First_Name, Last_Name, or Title. For some reason the only category that returns a result is Title. If I type a name that I know is in the first name or last name I get no results. I'm new to SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Query: `SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE First_Name OR Last_Name OR Title LIKE "Hollis"`

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FISnc.png)

[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngbhF.png)

Comment: The `OR` operator does not do what you think it does. [Please familiarize yourself with the concepts of disjunctive vs conjunctive operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
WHERE First_Name OR Last_Name OR Title LIKE "Hollis"
```

Is not doing what you expect.  It is treating `First_Name` and `Last_Name` as boolean conditions.  That means that it is converting them to numbers and checking if the number is or is not `0`.  In fact, with no leading digits, the names are probably always `0`, so they evaluate to "false".

What you seem to intend is:

```
WHERE 'Hollis' IN (First_Name, Last_Name, Title)
```